# Swift positioning of the button in custom toolbar (Google design material)

Tags: swift, material-design

I have a custom toolbar create by the google design material framework. Also, I would like to implement 3 button in the toolbar(at left, center and right). However, I could only find `.rightControl` and `.leftControl`. It could only place the button on the right or left. **Which I would like to implement one at the center**. How could I do it programmatically?

```
  private var toolbar: Toolbar!


private func prepareToolbar() {
toolbar = Toolbar()

toolbar.width = 400
toolbar.height = 80.0




let image: UIImage? = MaterialIcon.cm.settings
let logoBtn = UIImage(named: "buttonlogo") as UIImage?

// Menu button.
let menuButton: IconButton = IconButton()
menuButton.pulseColor = MaterialColor.white
menuButton.tintColor = MaterialColor.white
menuButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
menuButton.setImage(image, forState: .Highlighted)

let logoButton: IconButton = IconButton()
logoButton.setImage(logoBtn, forState: .Normal)

  let searchButton: IconButton = IconButton()
  searchButton.pulseColor = MaterialColor.white
  searchButton.tintColor = MaterialColor.white
  searchButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
  searchButton.setImage(image, forState: .Highlighted)


toolbar.rightControls = [logoButton]
//toolbar.rightControls = [searchButton]  <---------
toolbar.leftControls = [menuButton]


view.addSubview(toolbar)


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Material

class ViewController: UIViewController {
/// Reference for containerView.
private var containerView: UIView!

/// Reference for Toolbar.
private var toolbar: Toolbar!

let addButton: IconButton = IconButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    prepareView()
    prepareContainerView()
    prepareToolbar()
}

/// General preparation statements.
private func prepareView() {
    view.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.white
}

/// Prepares the containerView.
private func prepareContainerView() {
    containerView = UIView()
    view.layout(containerView).edges(top: 100, left: 20, right: 20)
}

/// Prepares the toolbar
private func prepareToolbar() {
    toolbar = Toolbar()
    containerView.addSubview(toolbar)

    // Title label.
    toolbar.title = " "
    toolbar.titleLabel.textColor = MaterialColor.white
    toolbar.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    // Detail label.
    //toolbar.detail = "Build Beautiful Software"
    //toolbar.detailLabel.textColor = MaterialColor.white

    var image: UIImage? = MaterialIcon.cm.menu

    // Menu button.
    let menuButton: IconButton = IconButton()
    menuButton.pulseColor = MaterialColor.white
    menuButton.tintColor = MaterialColor.white
    menuButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    menuButton.setImage(image, forState: .Highlighted)


    // Add button
    image = MaterialIcon.cm.add
    addButton.pulseColor = MaterialColor.white
    addButton.tintColor = MaterialColor.white
    addButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    addButton.setImage(image, forState: .Highlighted)
    addButton.center = toolbar.center

    let space = IconButton()
    space.userInteractionEnabled = false
    //spacd.pulseColor = UIColor

    // Search button.
    image = MaterialIcon.cm.search
    let searchButton: IconButton = IconButton()
    searchButton.pulseColor = MaterialColor.white
    searchButton.tintColor = MaterialColor.white
    searchButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    searchButton.setImage(image, forState: .Highlighted)

    /*
     To lighten the status bar - add the
     "View controller-based status bar appearance = NO"
     to your info.plist file and set the following property.
     */
    toolbar.backgroundColor = MaterialColor.blue.base
    toolbar.leftControls = [menuButton]
    toolbar.rightControls = [searchButton]
    toolbar.addSubview(addButton)
    toolbar.layout(addButton).center()

    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toolBarTapGestureRecognizer))
    toolbar.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func toolBarTapGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(addButton.bounds, tapGestureRecognizer.locationInView(addButton))) {
        addButton.pulse()
          NSLog("!!!!!!")
    }
}

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct, i implement the toolbar programmatically and i could not alter my storyboard.

Comment: I don't think I can apply the code to mine because I am using google material design framework.

Comment: The main idea is adding UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil) between your buttons

Comment: So, this solution helped?

Comment: I am sorry it is not helping because i could not add bar button in the google material design custom toolbar

Comment: I need more code to fix it. Could you cut the viewController with toolbar with material design?

Comment: That's all I got for the toolbar. In the code, I could place object in the `toolbar.leftControl = [object]` or `.rightControl` but they don't have middle for it

Comment: Can you send me the link of your material design framework?

Comment: Good news for you) check my answer)

Comment: nicely done!! btw I have created a tricky version lol I just simply add 2 extra button ` toolbar.leftControls = [menuButton, dummyBtn1 , dummyBtn2, centerBtn] ` set no image and disable userInteraction for the dummy button to create some space. However, I think your answer is great for me. I will edit my code to yours! Thanks mate!